# change duplicated index to columns of DataFrame of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem in dealing with some indexes and columns of `pd.DataFrame`.I have a DataFrame with duplicated indexes and I want to change the duplicated index to columns.

This is Dataframe:

[image]

As you see, the columns item have duplicated words,I wanna change the dataframe like this:

[image]
thank you very much

Comment: Welcome on SO, please read [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: You got my attention with >>>Dadaframe in the title. Welcome to SO, I tried to fix your question as best as possible. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I really hope you can help me solve this problem.